# when i am practicing <fmt:bundle/> and <fmt:message/> ,I get the wrong result like ???name?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I found some way to solve the similar question,but none of them make sense to me

Project directory:

[image: my project directory]

And my **properties file** content is

```
name=hello
```

this is my test code:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<fmt:bundle basename="messages1"></fmt:bundle>
<h1><fmt:message key="name"></fmt:message></h1>
```

this is my result `???name???`

Some people said 
Some solutions about how to solve the similar question is put the properties file under the `projectname/Java Resources/src/` but as you can see my **project directory** I put the proerties file in the 'right' place, but it makes no sense. Why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry，guys，I have found the problem, It's my mistake.I should write

```
<h1><fmt:message key="name"></fmt:message></h1>
```

in the body of `<fmt:bundle basename="com/messages1"></fmt:bundle>` instead of out of the body.
Anyway, thank you for taking time to see my question!:)